# IBM DB2 to SQL Server Migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, db2, database-migration, sqlbulkcopy

I am new to IBM DB2. Got a job to migrate data from DB2 to SQL Server. Able to connect DB2 database with IBM DB2 client via command prompt. We have already migrated Oracle data to SQL server with ASP.NET SQL Bulk Copy in C#. Need to migrate DB2 data on regular basis based on daily updates. Need details on how to run DB2 sql queries in any editor just like SQL plus for Oracle or Management Studio for SQL Server. Also need information on how to sync DB2 data with Bulk Copy in C#. Thank you in advance for the answers!

Comment: Another method would be to use SAS to connect to DB2, with bulkcopy over ODBC, that would take care of data conversion and runs relatively fast, especially if you multithread this. Also - very low impact on the Windows Server side, you can literally run queries during the heaviest loads.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways I currently do this are by using an ODBC connection to the db2 db and then:

1) set up a linked server so that queries can be directly run against db2.  The downside is that moving large tables is pretty slow.

2) use SSIS to move the data.  These can be created directly from SQL server for simple imports and for anything requiring more complicated coding such as cleaning up the data along the way (I have to remove lots of white space char fields), I use Visual Studio to create the SSIS packages.

Both methods can be set up as jobs and run automaticaly.